# URL with args does not reverse

Tags: django

I have the following url:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('app_common.views_settings',
    url(r'([\w-]+)/(\d+)/settings/$', 'settings', name="configuration_homepage"),
    url(r'(?P<short_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<product_id>\d+)/settings/modify/(?P<sim_id>\d+)/$', 'modify_sim', name="modify_sim"),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('app_common.views_operator',
    url(r'^operator/$', 'choose_operator', name="choose_operator"),
    url(r'^(?P<short_name>[\w-]+)/project/$', 'choose_project', name="choose_project"),
    url(r'([\w-]+)/(\d+)/$', 'set_product', name="set_product"),
    url(r'^(?P<short_name>[\w-]+)/$', 'set_operator', name="set_operator"),
)
```

I tried to reverse configuration homepage using:

```
url = reverse('configuration_homepage', kwargs={short_name, product_id})
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Some times it works, but other times if failed with this issue (short_name=OCI and product_id=1)

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'configuration_homepage' with arguments '(u'1', u'OCI')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

If you guys detect something wrong in my code fell free to tell me... I tried to give name to variable but urls are not found in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `args` instead of `kwargs`,

```
url = reverse('configuration_homepage', args=[short_name, product_id])
```

Comment: I used args={short_name, product_id} instead of your solution so the arguement was not taken in the good order... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `kwargs` is wrong, you are passing a `set()` instead of a `dict()`

What you (probably) want is:

```
url = reverse('configuration_homepage',
              kwargs={short_name: short_name, product_id: product_id})
```

This is one of the many reasons why I prefer `dict(a=1, b=2)` over `{a:1, b:2}` when possible,

Comment: The fact is in my 'configuration_homepage', there is no variable called short_name or product_id. If I add <short_name> and <product_id> in the url, i then have issue to reverse it...